# Extracting part of NSString

Tags: ios

I have a string like this:

```
<MCPeerID: 0x16e5cf00 DisplayName = Alex's ipad>
```

and I need to obtain from it the DisplayName, which can change length, so I can't just cut che final characters.

How can I extract the DisplayName attribute from this string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to parse the output of an object's `-description` method.  Do not do that.  That format is undefined and may change from release to release.

Instead, you should use the object's properties to retrieve the information you need.  In this case, the string indicates that the "DisplayName" is "Alex's ipad".  Perhaps you should see if the object you've got has a `displayName` property that would give you exactly the information you need...

Comment: Yes, there is a property for display name that you can use:
`@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSString *displayName`

Answer (score 2):

So you want to get "Alex's ipad"?

If so you can use:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

(using @" = " as separator) to split your string, then remove your last char (>).

Comment: Using `componentsSeparatedByString:` to get one part of a string is very inefficient (and kind of lazy).

Comment: @rmaddy So what do you suggest? Said that Dave's approach is correct if we are talking about descriptions, what about a generic string? Do you know more efficient ways of solving problems like this?

Comment: Sure. Use `rangeOfString` to find the `=` sign.

Comment: Maddy is right. componentsSeparatedByString creates multiple objects, and is inefficient. Much better to use rangeOfString to find the separator and then extract the string using one of the substring methods.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!! Looking at the documentation, I've found about rangeOfString method "finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver". If I have a string with more than one occurrence of "separator" (e.g. @"something = this, somethingelse = that") is still better to do all the logic using rangeOfString and substring methods?